# MongoDB : Aggregation Framework : group by consecutive status

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a process which creates statuses for all devices every 10 minutes.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536772ae3552606b54997995"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:14:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "online"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536772d03552606b54997996"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:18 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "online"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536772f63552606b54997997"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "offline"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536773283552606b54997998"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:16:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "online"
}
```

I want to aggregate the statuses to get a daily summary for each device :
for each consecutive status per device: beginning and end, status, id

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
            "sn" : 1,
            "from" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:14:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "to" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:18 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "status" : "online"
}
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
            "sn" : 1,
            "from" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "to" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "status" : "offline"
}
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),
            "sn" : 1,
            "from" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:16:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "to" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:16:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
            "status" : "online"
}
```

A simple group doesn't work because I can't check if statuses are consecutive.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536772ae3552606b54997995"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:14:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "grp" : 1,
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "online"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536772d03552606b54997996"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:18 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "grp" : 1,
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "online"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536772f63552606b54997997"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:15:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "grp" : 2,
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "offline"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("536773283552606b54997998"),
        "dt" : "Mon May 05 2014 13:16:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
        "grp" : 3,
        "sn" : 1,
        "status" : "online"
}
```

I can add a field which is incremented for each status change. I can group on this new field afterwards.

Is there a better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know there is no simple solution for this. Nevertheless, the incremented field you suggested sounds like a good and doable one to me.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question properly. Do you want to know how to do daily grouping based on a date using aggregation framework?

Comment: I want to do a chronological summary of the status of the day. I want to group all the consecutive identical status indicating the start time and end time. I hope this is more clear for you. Thanks

Comment: _id is unique across a collection - what represents each device in your original collection?

Comment: each device is represented by sn

Comment: are your dates really stored as strings?

Comment: no, as isodate. may be wrong in my example.